# handling nested callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynccallback

I need some help structuring my function w/ callbacks. The question: Is my logic performing how I imagine it?

```
app = getApp(function(val1, val2){
    helperFunction(val3, function(val4, val5, callbackTwo){
       //...logic
       var val6 = ....
       callbackTwo(val6)
    },
    function(val6){
        //logic
    });
};

function helperFunction(val3, callback, callbackTwo){
    //logic
    callback(val4, val5, callbackTwo);
}
```

Basically it works. However depending on my first anonymous `callback` function's logic, is there any chance that my `callbackTwo` function will be triggered before the assignment of `val6`?

Comment: Hmm. What is this being used for? I can't help but wonder if there's a clearer way to express it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty hilariously overwrought. Not sure why you're passing `callback2` into/out of `helperFunction`, since it doesn't *do* anything with it. Instead, just invoke your 2nd callback's code directly in your original callback. Unless you can give us a reason (there is no obvious one), just put that logic inside your first callback.

I've cleaned it up as best I can, but you haven't given us real, syntactically-valid JavaScript to work with here:

```
App = getApp(function(val1, val2) {
  helperFunction(val3, function(val4, val5) {
    //...logic
    var val6 = ....
    //logic that uses val6, originally from callback2
  });
};

function helperFunction(val3, callback){
  //logic
  callback(val4, val5);
}
```

Note that "logic that uses val6" can just be another function invocation, but there is no reason to make that function an argument to `helperFunction`'s callback.